Replacing dynamic exception specification with noexcept using a macro - How bad of an idea is this?
I'm using a library whose header uses dynamic exception specifications (both empty throw() and nonempty throw(some_exception_type)) in its header. I need to use this library in C++17, but I'm not able to edit the header directly. How bad of an idea is it to create a wrapper around the header like this:
// the-library-header-wrapper.h

template <typename... Ex>
constexpr inline bool parameter_pack_is_empty()
{
   return sizeof...(Ex) == 0u;
}

#define throw(...) noexcept(parameter_pack_is_empty<__VA_ARGS__>())

#include "the-library-header.h"

#undef throw

I'm using GCC so empty variadic macros is fine.
What are some potential pitfalls with this approach? Obviously it's bad style, but is there anything that I'm missing that would make this not work as I'm envisioning it?

Strictly speaking, defining a macro named throw is UB. See C++ preprocessor #define-ing a keyword. Is it standards conforming?

Why not leave the throws are they are? Do they come to the wrong conclusion?

@Brian61354270 Of course it's UB, I don't know what I expected, haha. Luckily for me, at least GCC explicitly seems to allow it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

@TedLyngmo Dynamic exception specifications were removed in C++17, so it won't compile

@NoamElul Ah, my bad, got it. Regarding not being able to edit the header directly, you could make a patch that you apply to it before using it. Is anything stopping that?

@Ted I'm not that familiar with how patches work. The library is installed system-wide and is used by other applications, so that complicates things. And we'd ideally want the patching to be integrated into the build system since otherwise it becomes difficult to update the library in all the different cross-build docker images we use (that's the main reason we don't want to actually edit the library in the first place)
Ultimately the correct answer is probably to fix how this library is installed to make it less terrible and easier to version, by including it as a submodule for example.

man patch should give an introduction to patches, but ok, since it's used all over the place and you are willing to make a macro that will also have to be used all over the place, I'd just make a custom version of the header and put it in the path where you planned on putting the header file with the macro. This path needs to come before the path to the original header file in your -I list. At least it's a start before making the proper change to the library.

Am I mistaken, or is noexcept not part of the function signature (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566968/3740047)? Wouldn't that mean that replacing throw with noexcept in the header results in linker errors? Or is it a header only library?

"just like the return type, exception specification is part of function type, but not part of the function signature". GCC and Clang definitely don't include noexcept information as part of the mangled name of a function, although it is included in the types of function pointers
